# Training neuralnet error: Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a sample data as following

```
item.train

units tmax tmin tavg dewpoint wetbulb heat cool snowfall preciptotal
   0   52   31   42       36      40   23    0        0       0.050
   0   50   31   41       26      35   24    0        0       0.010
   0   32   11   22        4      18   43    0        0       0.000
   0   28    9   19       -1      14   46    0        0       0.000
   0   38   25   32       13      25   33    0        0       0.000
   0   46   25   36       21      29   29    0       NA       0.005

stnpressure resultspeed RA BR FZ FG SN TS 
  29.78         3.6      1  1  1  1  0  0    
  29.44         9.8      0  0  0  0  0  0  
  29.67        10.8      0  0  0  0  0  0  
  29.86         6.3      0  0  0  0  0  0  
  29.67         6.9      0  0  0  0  0  0  
  29.68         0.3      0  0  0  0  1  0
```

I am trying to perform neuralnet

```
    library(neuralnet)
    neural.pred = neuralnet(units ~ tmax+tmin+tavg+dewpoint+wetbulb+heat+cool+snowfall+
preciptotal+stnpressure+resultspeed+
                        RA+BR+FZ+FG+SN+TS, 
                        data = item.train, linear.output = TRUE, hidden = c(5, 5),  err.fct = "sse", rep = 100)
```

And R gives me an error

> Error in x - y : non-conformable arrays

Help me what's wrong with my code or data, and how to solve it

Comment: To my knowledge your arrays should be the same size. I think that NA in `snowfall` might cause some issues so I would continue by editing these data accordingly and trying again. Does your code complain after you remove that NA?

Comment: After removing that NA, i tried. But it gives me the same error.

Comment: What did you replace it with? You have to make sure your arrays are sized similarly.

Comment: I just replace NA to 0. That's all.

Comment: Okay. Well, this is all I know about this subject. At least we tried.

Comment: removing the NAs, worked for me